# How to validate files using MIME?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to validate file types in server using php. Now at the moment I have validated it by checking the file extension type of the file. This works fines but the problem is that this isn't the best way to validate the file as a user an change lets say a text file into a jpeg and still be able to upload it.

So what I want to do is add another validation method, I also want to check the file's MIME type using php to recognize if the file is a image, video or audio.

So my question is how is it coded so that I can use MIME type in php to be able to validate a file? Also if I have an extremely large file, does it take a long time for the MIME validation to kick in or does it validate straight away?

Below is currently the code I have for Image only where it uses php code to check for file type:

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIME type lookup is usually pretty fast, and in PHP you can do it with the [`finfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) extension. Example:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, '/path/to/file.jpg'); // image/jpeg
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Also, you shouldn't rely on the `type` index of the `$_FILES` superglobal, as that value can be spoofed to anything an attacker may want. Same thing goes for the file extension of course.

Comment: Is finfo able to check for images, audio and video? Also if I use finfo and file extension types to validate files, is that enough or do I need more validation methods

Comment: Can you show me an example of lets say how finfo checks for a particular image type for example so I can see how it is done

Comment: @user1391585: Sure, one second.

Comment: @user1391585: Done. Also, if you're looking to only accept images, `exif_imagetype()` is simpler to use (`$mimetype = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype('/path/to/file.jpg'));`).

Comment: can finfo be also used for checking audio and video files or just images?

Comment: @user1391585: `finfo` can be used to check anything.

Comment: Oh that's cool, I will try and implement the code you have given me into the php and see if I can get it going. Thanks :) (P.S. How do I write if statement for finfo so that if $finfo matches then upload file)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getID3()](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/). Also [getimagesize](http://de.php.net/getimagesize) can reassure you.

The javascript code seems irrelevant here. Also as you probably know the types indicated in `$_FILES` should only be viewed as suggestions from the user/browser.

Comment: I am guessing getImagesize only works for image validation? Btw to code getImagesize do I only need to include this in my code for it to work: `$size = getimagesize($_FILES['fileImage']);` then do: `if ($size)`?

Comment: @user1391585 yes only for images (I was mislead by the code) [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#58166) is a good example for getimagesize. `if(!getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']){error}` should do the trick.